# Activity Indicator not working on a button Click in IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a form in which there are some textfields and dropdown after the selection when user hit a search button a new tableviewcontroller opens . In this table view controller it loads a function which brings data from service. the data loads with some time , now i want to use activity indicator between this time period when the data loads in table view i have used indicator ,but it not works . My code is,

```
    -(void)loadCustomerRecords

{

    _City = nil;

    _Title=nil;

    _Price=nil;

    _LandArea=nil;
    _Phone=nil;
    _Image1=nil;
    _location=nil;
    _name=nil;
    _email=nil;
    _descrip=nil;
    _type=nil;
    _rooms=nil;
    _washroom=nil;
    _floor=nil;
    _Id=nil;
    _status=nil;



    NSUserDefaults *string = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

    NSString *string1 = [string stringForKey:@"country"];

    NSString *string2 = [string stringForKey:@"city"];

    NSString *string3 = [string stringForKey:@"proptype"];

    NSString *string4 = [string stringForKey:@"propstatus"];

    NSString *string5 = [string stringForKey:@"proparea"];

    NSString *string6 = [string stringForKey:@"area"];

    NSString *string7 = [string stringForKey:@"min"];

    NSString *string8 = [string stringForKey:@"max"];




    if ([string4 isEqualToString:@"Property Status"]) {

        string4 = @"";
    }


    if ([string3 isEqualToString:@"Property Type"]) {

        string3 = @"";
    }


    if([string5 isEqualToString:@"Property Area"]){

        string5 = @"";


    }
    else{

        //concatenating strings
    NSString *strappend=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",string6,string5];

    string5 = strappend;
    }

    if ([string7 isEqualToString:@""] && [string8 isEqualToString:@""]) {

        string7 = @"";
        string8 = @"";
    }


    NSLog(@"AREA : %@", string5);


    NSLog(@"country %@",string1);

    NSLog(@"city %@",string2);

    NSLog(@"property_type %@",string3);

    NSLog(@"propertystatus %@",string4);

    NSLog(@"propertyarea %@",string5);

    NSLog(@"area %@",string6);

    NSLog(@"min %@",string7);

    NSLog(@"max %@",string8);


    CustomTableViewCell *check=[[CustomTableViewCell alloc]init];

    check.indicator.hidden=NO;

    [check.indicator startAnimating];

    NSURLSessionConfiguration *defaultConfigObject = [NSURLSessionConfiguration 

defaultSessionConfiguration];

    NSURLSession *defaultSession = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:

 defaultConfigObject delegate: nil delegateQueue: [NSOperationQueue mainQueue]];

    NSString *urlLinkA=@"My URL";


    NSURL * url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlLinkA];

    NSMutableURLRequest * urlRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];


    NSString *parameters = [NSString 

stringWithFormat:@"country=%@&city=%@&propertytype=%@&propertstatus=%@&propertyare

a=%@",string1,string2,string3,string4,string5];

    NSLog(@"parameter %@",parameters);

    [urlRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

    [urlRequest setHTTPBody:[parameters dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    NSURLSessionDataTask * dataTask =[defaultSession 

dataTaskWithRequest:urlRequest
                                                       completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
                                                           [check.indicator stopAnimating];

                                                           NSLog(@"Response:%@ %@\n", response, error);
                                                           if(error == nil)
                                                           {



                                                               NSDictionary *dictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:&error];

                                                               NSLog(@"MY Response %@ ", dictionary);

                                                               NSArray *results = [dictionary objectForKey:@"property_data"];
                                                               NSLog(@"RESULT %@ ", results);




                                                               _City = [NSMutableArray array];
                                                               _Phone = [NSMutableArray array];
                                                               _LandArea = [NSMutableArray array];
                                                               _location = [NSMutableArray array];
                                                               _name = [NSMutableArray array];
                                                               _email = [NSMutableArray array];
                                                               _descrip = [NSMutableArray array];
                                                               _type = [NSMutableArray array];
                                                               _rooms = [NSMutableArray array];
                                                               _washroom = [NSMutableArray array];
                                                               _floor = [NSMutableArray array];
                                                               _Id = [NSMutableArray array];
                                                               _Price = [NSMutableArray array];
                                                               _Title = [NSMutableArray array];

                                                               for (NSDictionary * oneCustomer in results)
                                                               {
                                                                   // Create a new Customer record

                                                                   StringData * newCustomer = [[StringData alloc] init];



                                                                   newCustomer.title1 = [oneCustomer objectForKey:@"property_title"];
                                                                   NSLog(@"ID: %@ ", newCustomer.title1);
                                                                   newCustomer.Area = [oneCustomer objectForKey:@"land_area"];
                                                                   NSLog(@"Country: %@ ", newCustomer.Area);
                                                                   newCustomer.images = [oneCustomer objectForKey:@"images"];

                                                                   NSLog(@"IMAGE: %@ ", newCustomer.images);

                                                                   newCustomer.City = [oneCustomer objectForKey:@"city"];
                                                                   NSLog(@"CITY: %@ ", newCustomer.City);

                                                                   newCustomer.phoneno = [oneCustomer objectForKey:@"dealer_phone"];
                                                                   NSLog(@"ID: %@ ", newCustomer.phoneno);

                                                                   newCustomer.location = [oneCustomer objectForKey:@"location"];
                                                                   NSLog(@"ID: %@ ", newCustomer.location);

                                                                   newCustomer.property_description = [oneCustomer objectForKey:@"property_description"];
                                                                   NSLog(@"ID: %@ ", newCustomer.property_description); 

                                                                   newCustomer.property_type = [oneCustomer objectForKey:@"property_type"]; 
                                                                   NSLog(@"ID: %@ ", newCustomer.property_type); 

                                                                   newCustomer.property_id = [oneCustomer objectForKey:@"property_id"]; 
                                                                   NSLog(@"ID: %@ ", newCustomer.property_id); 

                                                                   newCustomer.status_property = [oneCustomer objectForKey:@"status_property"]; 
                                                                   NSLog(@"ID: %@ ", newCustomer.status_property); 

                                                                   newCustomer.status = [oneCustomer objectForKey:@"status"]; 
                                                                   NSLog(@"ID: %@ ", newCustomer.status); 

                                                                   newCustomer.dealer_email = [oneCustomer objectForKey:@"dealer_email"]; 
                                                                   NSLog(@"ID: %@ ", newCustomer.phoneno); 

                                                                   newCustomer.dealer_name = [oneCustomer objectForKey:@"dealer_name"]; 
                                                                   NSLog(@"ID: %@ ", newCustomer.dealer_name); 

                                                                   newCustomer.bath = [oneCustomer objectForKey:@"bathrooms"]; 
                                                                   NSLog(@"ID: %@ ", newCustomer.bath); 

                                                                   newCustomer.rooms = [oneCustomer objectForKey:@"rooms"]; 
                                                                   NSLog(@"ID: %@ ", newCustomer.rooms); 

                                                                   newCustomer.floors = [oneCustomer objectForKey:@"floors"]; 
                                                                   NSLog(@"ID: %@ ", newCustomer.floors); 

                                                                   newCustomer.country = [oneCustomer objectForKey:@"country"]; 
                                                                   NSLog(@"ID: %@ ", newCustomer.country); 

                                                                   newCustomer.Price = [oneCustomer objectForKey:@"price"];
                                                                   NSLog(@"ID: %@ ", newCustomer.Price);

                                                                   // Add our new Customer record to our NSMutableArray 
                                                                   [_Title addObject:newCustomer]; 


                                                                   NSString *imageURL = @"http://www.pk.house/frontend/propertyimages/"; 


                                                                   NSString *string3 = [imageURL stringByAppendingString:newCustomer.images]; 

                                                                   newCustomer.images = string3; 

                                                                   NSLog(@"Image URL %@",string3); 


                                                                   // addObject:[oneCustomer objectForKey:@"property_title"]];
                                                                  // NSLog(@"TET %@",_Title);


                                                                   [_Price addObject:[oneCustomer objectForKey:@"price"]]; 
                                                                   NSLog(@"TET %@",_Price);

                                                                   [_Image1 addObject:[oneCustomer objectForKey:@"images"]];
                                                                   NSLog(@"TET %@",_Image1);

                                                                   [_City addObject:[oneCustomer objectForKey:@"city"]];
                                                                   NSLog(@"TET %@",_City);

                                                                   [_Phone addObject:[oneCustomer objectForKey:@"dealer_phone"]];
                                                                   NSLog(@"TET %@",_Phone);

                                                                   [_name addObject:[oneCustomer objectForKey:@"dealer_name"]];
                                                                   NSLog(@"TET %@",_name);

                                                                   [_email addObject:[oneCustomer objectForKey:@"dealer_email"]];
                                                                   NSLog(@"TET %@",_email);

                                                                   [_rooms addObject:[oneCustomer objectForKey:@"rooms"]];
                                                                   NSLog(@"TET %@",_rooms);

                                                                   [_washroom addObject:[oneCustomer objectForKey:@"bathrooms"]];
                                                                   NSLog(@"TET %@",_washroom);

                                                                   [_floor addObject:[oneCustomer objectForKey:@"floors"]];
                                                                   NSLog(@"TET %@",_floor);

                                                                   [_type addObject:[oneCustomer objectForKey:@"price"]];
                                                                   NSLog(@"TET %@",_type);

                                                                   [_descrip addObject:[oneCustomer objectForKey:@"property_description"]];
                                                                   NSLog(@"TET %@",_descrip);

                                                                   [_LandArea addObject:[oneCustomer objectForKey:@"land_area"]];
                                                                   NSLog(@"TET %@",_LandArea);

                                                                   [_Id addObject:[oneCustomer objectForKey:@"property_id"]];
                                                                   NSLog(@"TET %@",_Id);


                                                                   [_location addObject:[oneCustomer objectForKey:@"location"]];
                                                                   NSLog(@"TET %@",_location);

                                                                                                                              }
                                                               dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                                                                   // This code will run once the JSON-loading section above has completed.


                                                                   [self.tableView reloadData];
                                                               });




                                                               NSString *status=[dictionary valueForKey:@"property_data"];
                                                               NSLog(@"Status:%@",status);

                                                                                                                      }
                                                           else{
                                                               NSLog(@"network error:");


                                                           }

                                                       }];
    [dataTask resume];


}
```

Comment: kindly paste relevant code regarding your issue.

Comment: please don't post full code .. just post  which part of code not working you think

Comment: actually the function i have written is load in viewdidload function. Now i'm asking that do i write inicator startanimation in this or before this. @TusharSharma

Comment: start animation at the time you are fetching response from server or database, and stop animation once you get proper response. And do call UI related task on main thread.

Comment: this function starts from viewdidload method, i have to start right bedore it is called? @TusharSharma

Comment: yes start animation while your data is being fetched and stop when it is displayed on UI.

Comment: let me try this

Comment: Its not working bro. I have star indicator annimation like this,  CustomTableViewCell *checks=[[CustomTableViewCell alloc]init];
    checks.indicator.hidden=NO;
    [checks.indicator startAnimating];
    [self loadCustomerRecords];

Comment: and stop like this, }                                     dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
 // This code will run once the JSON-loading section above has completed.
  CustomTableViewCell *check=[[CustomTableViewCell alloc]init];
 [check.indicator stopAnimating];
 check.indicator.hidden=YES;
 [self.tableView reloadData];
 });
NSString *status=[dictionary valueForKey:@"property_data"];
  NSLog(@"Status:%@",status);
  }
  else{ NSLog(@"network error:");
 }

Comment: check above. @TusharSharma

Answer (score 0):

Try this-

```
  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
         // This block will be executed asynchronously on the main thread.
            [check.indicator stopAnimating];
       });
```

Comment: from where i should starAnimation? @Abhishek Jain

Comment: You can start just after loadCustomerRecords function starts.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code:

```
[self startYourAnimation];
[self performSelector:@selector(loadCustomerRecords) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.3];
```

It will help you show the animation when you try to load or process rest of things.

Comment: where to end it than? @Nirmalsinh

Comment: You can stop in loadCustomer method.

Comment: Comment second line and check if you get animation or not.

Comment: Actually its giving error on line [self startAnimation];. @Niramlsinh

Comment: When we make outlet of activity indicator in UITablview class it gives error , than we have to make its outlet in customcell class